# how to resolve loading error on mongodb compass for windows os?

Tags: mongodb

The screen got stuck on *initializing page* on **mongodb compass**. I tried reinstalling the application but the issue still persists.

Comment: could you please add some more details in your question.

Comment: I installed mongodb compass, when I tried to open the application it got stuck on initializing page, so I reinstalled it but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I have a same issue, but I found a solution.

Let me tell you why this issue came, when you install mongoDB compass.

MongoDB compass is made using electron and electron have many dependencies. And one of them is `windows-release`. This dependency try to find details about your OS and for do that dependency have commands like `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem` and `wmic get os Caption`. And for some systems, this command threw and error, so your screen stuck on loading page.

What is the solution?
Simple solution is to add path of `wmic` in environment variable, because wmic is somewhere in your system32 folder and easy to find it.

How to do that?

1. right click on `my computer` and select `properties`
2. selcet `Advanced system settings`
3. click on `Environment variables..`
4. select `PATH` from user variables and click on `Edit` button.
5. don't erase but add semicolon at the end and paste this `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`
6. click ok until all popup box gone.

now start mongoDB compass.
And it works! WOW.